Nextjs static export in sub folder, image and manifest.webmanifest src 404 (Not Found)
I am using nextjs 14+, app route and next-intl, My nextjs project image inside public/images/
This how i use Image
<Image
  src='images/photo.jpg'
  alt="category"
  fill
/>

I tested on localhost. I tried to put the out folder of export into localhost/out/
I set it in next.config.mjs
 output: 'export',
 basePath: '/out',
 assetPrefix: '/out',
 trailingSlash: true,

The content of the web page is displayed normally, but all images cannot be displayed.
GET http://localhost/images/photo.jpg 404 (Not Found)

The reason is that it is linked to http://localhost/images/.
The correct location of the image is http://localhost/out/images/.
 is also connected to the root directory, the correct answer should be `http://localhost/out/manifest.webmanifest`
This problem bothers me a lot. I tried for several hours without success.
How do I set this up? I believe this is handled within next.config.mjs
